# Ckeditor ContentsCSS not loading always

Tags: css, ckeditor

If been looking on the internet for a solution for this problem. Butt the error doesn't always happen either.

What i need to do: i need to load External css from another website in the Ckeditor view. I'm doing this with the ContentsCSS config function on replace.

Sometimes one of my 4 stylesheets doesn't load. for the record, I don't see any error.. It just won't load.

This is the only reference i found:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/config.contentsCss-not-work-Firefox

Does anyone know a solution for this?

B.t.w it only happens in firefox as far is i know.

Comment: It happens only the first time when the page is loaded btw after a full cache clean.. After that i think the stylesheets are cached.. and therefore they do load. They only solution that i still have to try and have thought off is to add script tags manualy to the editor iframe

Comment: Is that CSS not loaded at all? I mean... what does network console tell you?

Comment: I've been searching in the network console. But i can't find neither one of 4.. at least not yet.. It's i'm working with Liferay a CMS System and the system loads around 80 css files? therefore it's kinda hard to find it.. Should the external file show the url as name? because that doesn't show as far as i know.. neither when they are loaded. If you can give me a hint how the name would look like it will help a lot. haha

Comment: In fact I don't have any idea what can cause this behaviour except one thing - race condition while loading many editors. Is this your case? I mean this issue: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6504

Comment: It sounds kinda related indeed because on reload or even on switch of the Wysiwyg mode the stylsheets do load.. So possible the stylesheets are loaded but to late.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28444/discussion-between-spons-and-reinmar)

Comment: One thing more that my tester found. Is the fact that it only happens when you cleaned all Cached.. Then the first editor call it loads external css 1 of the 4 after that it loads number 2 of the 4. And the last 2 css´s i couldn´t check yet.

Comment: @reinmar, is there a event to wait till external css styles are loaded..  I'm thnking that it might be the problem that the css files are loaded later then the editor.. Example will be made tomorrow i hope.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-stylesSet